# passing parameters between pages in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parameter-passing

In WordPress, how can I open a different page while passing it a parameter?
For example, if I have a page which is a list of shops I want to put a button next to each shop which when clicked will redirect to a shop page. so I need to pass the shop id so the right values will load in the shop page.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just construct the URL for each store when you are rendering the page and then pass the arguments in query string. Your url's could look like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/view_store.php?store_id=2"><img button></a>
```

Comment: First, because I don't want the parameters to be exposed. Second - it's not good SEO.